# How to transpile one particular file / folder inside node_module from es6 to es5 using babel-loader?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, node-modules, babeljs

1.IE11 doesn’t support ES6 syntax in code . It will throw error if it encounters any ES6 syntax. 
2.We are having ES6 syntax  inside “node_module / types.js/types.min.js” file and we were excluding node_module inside webpack.config.js .So its throwing error in IE11 as babel-loader is not transpiling types.min.js from es6 to es5 .

I want to include only ***\node_modules\types.js*** for transpiling inside webpack.config.js file. Or any better Solution ???

***Tried***:

`exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(types.js)\/).*/`,

but its including whole node_module.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,        
        // exclude: /node_modules/,
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(types.js)\/).*/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve('jquery'),
        use: ['expose-loader?jQuery', 'expose-loader?$']
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: check this once https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2031

Comment: 'exclude: /node_modules(?!(\/|\\)types.js)/,' -- this statement worked . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exclude: /node_modules(?!(\/|\\)types.js)/,
```

here `types.js` is your module name you want to include .

Comment: How to transpile CSS and images as these types of files are not getting transpiled when using babel-loader but js/jsx are getting transpiled.